# Understanding Probability Density Functions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, matlab, density-function, intuition

I am having trouble understanding probability density functions. What exactly is a probability density function? Does it give you the probability of a value occurring?

See my MATLAB code below:

```
x = randn(1000,1); % generates 1000 numbers from the standard normal distribution
y = normpdf(x,0,1);
```

So what y tells me is basically what is the probability of an element in X occurring right? No, it is basically the f(x) value for x, for the Gaussian Density function right?

In this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (wikipedia), it says:

> In probability theory, a probability density function (PDF), or
>   density of a continuous random variable, is a function that describes
>   the relative likelihood for this random variable to take on a given
>   value. The probability of the random variable falling within a
>   particular range of values is given by the integral of this variable’s
>   density over that range—that is, it is given by the area under the
>   density function but above the horizontal axis and between the lowest
>   and greatest values of the range.

So what is the difference of the relative likelihood vs probability?

Also if somebody wants to accurately calculate the probability of a random variable, then he can just take a really small integral area right (close to zero)?